# Return an array with all the elements of the passed in array but the last

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

Instructions:

> Write a function called `getAllElementsButLast`.
>
> Given an array, `getAllElementsButLast` returns an array with all the elements but the last.

Below is my code that will not pass the requirements for the question.  I am not sure why this is not correct even though I am getting back all the elements besides the last.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function getAllElementsButLast(array) {
    return arr.splice(0, arr.length - 1)
}
getAllElementsButLast(arr) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: if I do:   arr2 = arr.pop() and return arr it gives me the same answer but still not passing the test

Comment: You're mixing up `array` and `arr`.

Comment: Just to add on to @user2357112's comment, you're modifying `arr` explicitly in your function. Your parameter is not doing anything. I could pass `getAllElementsButLast(ANYTHING);` and it would work. Change `arr` to `array` in the two references of  your`return` line.

Comment: pshhh thank you. I should remove my name as my id

Comment: You should probably use `.slice()`, not `.splice()`, since the latter also modifies the input array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why it's not accepted is because with `splice()` you **change** the *input* array. And that's not what you want. Instead use `slice()`. This method **doesn't change** the *input* array.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function getAllElementsButLast(array) {
  var newArr = array.slice(0, array.length - 1);
  return newArr;
}

var r = getAllElementsButLast(arr);
console.log(r);
console.log(arr);
```